# How can I use variable interactions in vb.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net, variables

I am trying to create a new app that uses a SQL database to pull out data based on user input/selections.
For this I am using:

- 1 combo box that displays the projects
- 1 combo box that displays the available columns to be used while querying the table
- 1 text box in which the user can input data to complete the query requirements

Also I am using params to query the database as I found out this is the right way to do it (to avoid any unwanted SQL injection attacks).
So far the sub looks like this:

```
 Private Sub FindItem()
    SQL.AddParam("@item", "%" & TxtItem.Text & "%")
    SQL.AddParam("@project", "%" & cbxproj.Text & "%")
    SQL.AddParam("@column", "%" & cbxcol.Text & "%")


    loadgrid("Select
              SourceServer
             ,ProjectId
             ,ProjectName
             ,MasterTitle
             ,BugIdPrefix
             ,BugId
             ,BugTitle
             ,BugDescription
             ,EpicName
             ,Submitter
             ,AssignedByPerson
             ,IssueType
             ,Priority
             ,Severity
             ,PlatformFound
             ,ProgressStatus
             ,Resolution 
             ,CloseReason
             ,Feature
             ,SubFeature
             ,FoundVersion
             ,AffectedVersion
             ,FixVersion
             ,GameArea
             ,BuildFound
             ,BuildFixed
             ,ClFixed
             ,Component
             ,Label
             ,CurrentOwner
             ,TestType
             ,TimeEstimated
             ,TimeRemaining
             ,TimeLogged
             ,Studio
             ,TestTeam
             ,ScrumTeam
             ,createdtime_utc as 'Date Created'
             ,assignedtime_utc as 'Date Assigned'
             ,closedtime_utc as 'Date Closed'
             ,lastmodifiedtime_utc as 'Date Last Modified'
            From mydatabase where ProjectName like @project and @column like @item")
End Sub
```

So the issue is that if I select a project and a column and then press the search button, the results are displayed. Once I input some text in the text box, there are no results displayed whatsoever.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I believe `and @column like @item` is the problem - you can't usually parameterize *names* as you're doing with `@column`. Instead, you should have a whitelist of known column names (to avoid SQL injection attacks etc) and then put the column name directly in the SQL

Comment: Think about a method in VB.NET.  Could you use a parameter to pass in the name of a variable or property?  Of course not; parameters are for values, not identifiers.  The same is true of SQL. There are ways you can specify an identifier using text in both VB and SQL but they are not so simple as there are serious security considerations.

Comment: I see, well that explains all. I will try to rewrite my code since this ship is sailed. Thanks for the clarification !